# icecast + awstats or webalizer

Tags: streaming, icecast, awstats

I'm using Icecast2 and with the stats file, I can only see the count of current listeners and the listeners peak.

I want a full report of statistics with minutes, hours, days, weeks, months and years of listeners.

I've seen aWstats and Webalizer and these are great tools to use. Now i've installed Awstats and I see the page but with 0 listeners and thats not correct, so I think that I haven't configured the file correctly..

These were my settings:

```
LogFile="/var/log/icecast2/access.log”
LogType= S
LogFormat= 1
SiteDomain=“jermaineart.com”
HostAliases="jermaineart.com localhost 127.0.0.1”
DNSLookup=1
```

Can anyone help me out with this configuration or with another software for the statistics?

Comment: I'm not sure if it ever got merged, but someone patched webalizer long time ago "streamalizer" to support Icecast logs. As the logs differ from the common httpd log format by having the connection duration as the last column.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, but I can't find any Streamalizer.

Comment: try this: http://webalizer.bzhtec.com/ - looks like the original page of the fork is still around after all these years. :-)

Comment: Nice, thank you! btw. I've seen that my icecast access.log is empty..

Comment: Windows? point to a location that's actually writable by the Icecast process. The programs directory often isn't.

Comment: Nope it is on linux ubuntu 14.04. Awstats is working fine now, but still not creating stats. Because icecast is not logging in access.log

Comment: Are you starting Icecast properly as a service? `/etc/init.d/icecast2 start` or `systemctl start icecast2.service`. The logs will be owned by `icecast2:icecast`, so the user that awstats or webalizer runs as MUST be part of the `icecast` group or run as `icecast2`.